# View C++ standard library documentation on mousehover in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition, with the toolsets "Desktop development with C++" and "Linux development with C++" installed. Now when I use some class/method from the standard library, I only see the method signature:

[image]

What I'd like to see as well in that same popup is a short description/help of the method and the parameters. Is this usually working out of the box? If not, is there any plugin/extension for that functionality?
If I develop a console app for Linux (with the same VS installation), the documentation is showing correctly:

[image]

Looking into the header files of the standard libraries confirms that the Windows library just doesn't contain those doc comments. Any way to get them?

Answer (score 1):

In order to display function information, you must make sure that the library you are using has comments. Although it is not fast enough, after jumping to the page of the class, manually selecting the method to view is a recommended way. I suggest you select the class and method you want to view, then press F1, it will automatically enter the corresponding MSDN.